# Last-child not working with classes. Last-of-type also not working

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

I am trying to select the :last-child of a series of wordpress posts (with the same class) in my style.css file.
Here is a simplified version of my document structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
  <!--start .post-->
  <div id="post-33" class="hentry p1 post">
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="url">Post 1</a></h2>
            <div class="entry-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
        </div>
  <!--end  .post -->
  <!--start .post-->
  <div id="post-24" class="hentry p1 post">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="url">Post 2</a></h2>
    <div class="entry-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end  .post -->
  <!--start .post-->
  <div id="post-24" class="hentry p1 post">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="url">Post 3</a></h2>
    <div class="entry-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end  .post -->

        <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
            <div class="nav-previous"></div>
            <div class="nav-next"></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #container -->
```

I have tried this and although it works fine with the :first-child selector it does not work at all with the :last-child.

```
.post .entry-content { 
    background-color: pink; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.post:first-child .entry-content { 
    background-color: red; 
    border-bottom: 0px solid;
}

.post:last-child .entry-content { 
    background-color: yellow; 
    border-bottom: 0px solid;
}
```

Any thoughts? 
Here is the live version of my site: http://dev.visualvisual.com/

Comment: The last element of class `post` isn't the last-child of its parent; and there is no `last-of-class` pseudo-class selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nth-of-type` and `nth-last-of-type`.

```
.post:nth-of-type(1) .entry-content { 
    background-color: red; 
    border-bottom: 0px solid;
}

.post:nth-last-of-type(2) .entry-content { 
    background-color: yellow; 
    border-bottom: 0px solid;
}
```

`first-child` and `last-child`, are, like the name suggests, for operating on children, so you'd want to use `#content:last-child` to find last element (not necessarily `.post` though).

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/yawpvE?editors=1100)

Comment: This won't work, `:last-of-type` doesn't look at the class-names of an element, only its 'tag-name'.

Comment: Thanks Tomek. thanks but it didn't work... same result:  the :first-of-type works but the  :last-of-type doesn't.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks Tomek. nth-of-type and nth--of-type did the job. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad I helped ;-)

Comment: Daję piwo! Nie do końca rozumiem zasadę działania tej (2) ale ostatni div z czterech z tą samą klasą nie wyświetla ramki i o to mi chodziło. Dzięki wielkie :)